# Google AdMob game crashes unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Build without having googleAdMob works fine , however after adding adMob test ads builds crashes on smartphone

Comment: please show us your error log and the line that error happens

Comment: there is no error in console build is succeeded but on smartphone when you run it says game is stopped

Comment: plug the phone to `pc` and use `logcat` to see the error

Comment: Could you post your android manifest

Comment: ı have handled it I closed the custom gradle template in player settings now it worked fine on smartphone. Also, I am going to try your solution thanks for advising